# I cannot make a function to delete likes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to make simple voting system for comments.
Just one button "voteup", and if the user has already clicked it, it changes to "delete vote". And everything seems to work, except for the voice removal feature. If I click "delete vote" an error `Couldn't find Post with 'id'=11` appears.
And I do not understand why this is so, because this is, in fact, one method that is used both for voting and for removing one's vote. Only in one case does everything work, but in the other not.

votes_controller:

```rb
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_comment
  before_action :find_vote, only: [:destroy]
def create
  if already_voted?
    flash[:notice] = "You can't like more than once"
  else
      @comment.votes.create(author_id: current_author.id)
  end
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def destroy
  if !(already_voted?)
    flash[:notice] = "Cannot unlike"
  else
    @vote.destroy
  end
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

private
def find_comment
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
end

def already_voted?
  Vote.where(author_id: current_author.id, comment_id:
  params[:comment_id]).exists?
end

def find_vote
   @vote = @comment.votes.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

Votes  elements in _comment.html.erb:

```rb
<% pre_vote = comment.votes.find { |vote| vote.author_id == current_author.id} %>
        <% if pre_vote %>
          <%= button_to 'Delete Vote', post_comment_vote_path(comment, pre_vote), method: :delete %>
        <% else %>
          <%= button_to 'UpVote', post_comment_votes_path(post, comment), method: :post %>
        <% end %>
      <p><%= comment.votes.count %> <%= (comment.votes.count) == 1 ? 'Like' : 'Likes'%></p>
```

**UPD**
This post has id - 3, not 11.
The comment has id 11.
For some reason, it confused everything during the removal of like.

**UPD 2**

Migration:

```rb
  def change
    create_table :votes do |t|
      t.references :comment, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :author, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

vote.rb :

```rb
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :author
end
```

comment.rb and author.rb : `has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy`

Comment: Pls, add migrations and models to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing an argument from your delete link. Try adding `post` as the first argument:

```
<%= button_to 'Delete Vote', post_comment_vote_path(post, comment, pre_vote), method: :delete %>
```